# How to restrict some sensors to send data every few seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I'm building an app that will read sensor data and store it into kafka with rest controller as middleman. (First time working with sensors)
UI consists of Sensor name + switch button to start or stop sending sensor data.
I'm trying to regulate how much of sensor data is send, because my android app just cant keep up with some of the sensors when they start with sending data, my UI just blocks.
I was testing with Emulator and sensors that have goldfish in there name, they work normally, Game rotation vector sensor, gravity sensor, and few others just start sending to much of data and app cant keep up. 
(I'm sending data with new thread each time).

```
SensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,sensor,500000000);
```

Changing samplingPeriod just didnt help at all, some sensors work normally and some just keep sending to much of data regardless of number.

I tried that, with each sensor change event, new Thread starts with sending data, so that UI would work normally, but my app cant keep up with some of the sensors.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
Thread t = new Thread(new MyOwnRunnableClass(sensorEvent,username));
t.start();
}
```

Comment: Hello your question is too broad but I will try to give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a native app to learn sensor
2. Don't create a thread every time a sensor updates because every thread generates over head. You want one thread to manage the sensors, one for ui. Should be enough.
3. Your sensor thread can drop readings if there are too many for your need (just process one out of ten)
4. Sampling rate used to work more or less when I used to develop in android native.
5. Read tutorials, using sensors is key in mobile so every framework has tutorials on how to do it the right way

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

second way:
you can set previous time in shared preferences and in OnSensorChanged method check if difference of current time and last time is over than 500000 set your data.

first way:
you can use alarm manager to do this every 500000 s;